# ManyToMany Composite Keys in Both tables that create the ManyToMany Relation how to annotate them

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa, many-to-many

I have a many to many relation between Trees and Nodes:

- Tree can have many nodes.
- Node can be in many trees.

I also have composite primary key in the Tree table and also in the Node table.

So my model classes look like so:

**Tree**:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tree")
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategies.SnakeCaseStrategy.class)
public class Tree {
    @EmbeddedId
    private TreeIdentifier treeIdentifier;
    private LocalDateTime creationDate;
}
```

**TreeIdentifier (this is the primary key of the Tree):**

```
@Embeddable
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategies.SnakeCaseStrategy.class)
public class TreeIdentifier implements Serializable {

    private String treeId;
    private String siteId;
    private Integer prodVersion;

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(prodVersion, siteId, treeId);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        TreeIdentifier other = (TreeIdentifier) obj;
        return Objects.equals(prodVersion, other.prodVersion) && Objects.equals(siteId, other.siteId)
                && Objects.equals(treeId, other.treeId);
    }

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
}
```

**Node:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "node")
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategies.SnakeCaseStrategy.class) 
public class Node {
    @EmbeddedId
    private NodeIdentifier nodeIdentifier;
    private Long nodePosition;
}
```

**NodeIdentifier (primary key of Node):**

```
@Embeddable
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategies.SnakeCaseStrategy.class)
public class NodeIdentifier implements Serializable {

    private String nodeId;
    private Integer nodeVersionId;

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(nodeId, nodeVersionId);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        NodeIdentifier other = (NodeIdentifier) obj;
        return Objects.equals(nodeId, other.nodeId) && Objects.equals(nodeVersionId, other.nodeVersionId);
    }

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

}
```

Now I am struggling to figure out how the intermediate table that surges because of this ManyToMany relation should look like in the code:

**TreeNode**:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tree_node")
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategies.SnakeCaseStrategy.class)
public class TreeNode {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer treeNodeId;
    private Tree tree;
    private Node node;
}
```

I was following Baeldung guides and so far I managed to make it work with saving Tree and Node in the database but now for the intermediate table can not figure out how should I annotate the fields properly (also how should I annotate the Tree and Node class too?), can you help me?

Guides I used:

- https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-many-to-many
- https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-composite-primary-keys

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of  [@MapsId](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/MapsId.html);
Perhaps this is what you are tying to achieve.

```
public class TreeNode {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer treeNodeId;
    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("treeIdentifier")
    private Tree tree;
    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("nodeIdentifier")
    private Node node;

}
```

Comment: Will try your solution too and get back with feedback, thank you!, would be cool if you add how the Tree and Node classes would look too, I think they are missing a List attribute too right?

Comment: I've used the same Tree and Node entities as provided above, i.e - they don't have the list attribute. Let me know if this solution helps.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use a bridge entity and create `one-to-many` and `many-to-one` relationship between `Tree`, `TreeNode` and `Node` entities as shown below:

***Tree:***

```
@Entity
public class Tree {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    // other fields, getter/setter, constructors, equals and hashCode methods ...

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "tree", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<TreeNode> treeNodes = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addTreeNode(TreeNode treeNode) {
        treeNodes.add(treeNode);
        treeNode.setTree(this);
    }

    public void removeTreeNode(TreeNode treeNode) {
        treeNodes.remove(treeNode);
        treeNode.setTree(null);
    }
}
```

***TreeNode:***

```
@Entity
public class TreeNode {

    @EmbeddedId
    private TreeNodeId treeNodeId = new TreeNodeId();

    // other fields, getter/setter, constructors, equals and hashCode methods ...

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId("treeId")
    @JoinColumn(name = "tree_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Tree tree;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId("nodeId")
    @JoinColumn(name = "node_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Node node;
}
```

***TreeNodeId:***

```
@Embeddable
public class TreeNodeId implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "tree_id", nullable = false)
    private Long treeId;

    @Column(name = "node_id", nullable = false)
    private Long nodeId;

    // getter/setter, equals and hashCode methods ...
}
```

***Node:***

```
@Entity
public class Node {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    // other fields, getter/setter, constructors, equals and hashCode methods ...

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "node", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<TreeNode> treeNodes = new HashSet<>();

    public void addTreeNode(TreeNode treeNode) {
        treeNodes.add(treeNode);
        treeNode.setNode(this);
    }

    public void removeTreeNode(TreeNode treeNode) {
        treeNodes.remove(treeNode);
        treeNode.setNode(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Will try it and get back with feedback, thank you

Comment: The @GeneratedValue on Tree and Node classes, the thing is that they both have composite primary keys, Tree primary key is composed by the treeId, siteId and prodVersion... same with the Node it has composed key, that is where I have the problem, the suggestion you are making is to make the primary Key an numeric autogenerated Id, and handle the logic of this other attributes being unique?

Comment: You can include 'prodVersion' to the composite key. The approach above is working and I think would work for 3 keys as well.

Comment: Im not understanding because I see you added     @Id@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)private Long id; but the problem is that I do not have that field on my database tables, for example the tree table is not autogenerating any field, its primary key is the treeId,siteId,prodVersion... So you are suggesting that I should add this id field to the table too?

Comment: My solution is based on using a bridge entity for many to many relationship as I explained. You can add other necessary field(s) to `TreeNodeId`, but regarding the relationship I mentioned, it works for the 2 composite keys.

Comment: Hey, do you see other way to do it without using bridge entity?

Comment: You can also use `@ManyToMany` relationship on both entities.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `@ManyToMany` annotation to establish the many-to-many relationship between the `Tree` and `Node` entities without using a bridge entity:

Tree:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tree")
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategies.SnakeCaseStrategy.class)
public class Tree {
    @EmbeddedId
    private TreeIdentifier treeIdentifier;
    private LocalDateTime creationDate;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "tree_node",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "tree_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "node_id")
    )
    private List<Node> nodes;
}
```

Node:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "node")
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategies.SnakeCaseStrategy.class) 
public class Node {
    @EmbeddedId
    private NodeIdentifier nodeIdentifier;
    private Long nodePosition;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "nodes")
    private List<Tree> trees;
}
```

In the `Tree` class, a `@ManyToMany` annotation to define the many-to-many relationship with the `Node` class. Specified the `@JoinTable` annotation to define the join table name and the join columns that link the `Tree` entity to the join table. The `inverseJoinColumns` attribute specifies the join columns that link the `Node` entity to the join table.

In the `Node` class, a `@ManyToMany` annotation with the `mappedBy` attribute, which tells `JPA` that the `nodes` field is the inverse side of the relationship and that the owning side is the `Tree` entity. This avoids creating a separate join entity to represent the many-to-many association.

Update:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tree_node")
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategies.SnakeCaseStrategy.class)
public class TreeNode {
    @EmbeddedId
    private TreeNodeId treeNodeId;
    
    @MapsId("treeId")
    @ManyToOne
    private Tree tree;
    
    @MapsId("nodeId")
    @ManyToOne
    private Node node;
}

@Embeddable
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategies.SnakeCaseStrategy.class)
public class TreeNodeId implements Serializable {
    private String treeId;
    private String nodeId;
    
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(treeId, nodeId);
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null || getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        TreeNodeId that = (TreeNodeId) obj;
        return Objects.equals(treeId, that.treeId) && Objects.equals(nodeId, that.nodeId);
    }
}
```

`TreeNode` has a composite primary key `TreeNodeId` that consists of the primary keys of both `Tree` and `Node` entities. The `tree` and `node` associations are mapped using `@MapsId`, which tells `JPA` to use the same primary key as the `TreeNodeId`

Comment: Looks very interesting, when you say at the end that "this avoids creating a separate join entity..." this means that the TreeNode class dissapiars by using this approach? How would it look if I wanted to keep the TreeNode class?

Comment: @BugsOverflow If you want to keep the `TreeNode` class, you can still use a composite primary key in the join table. The `TreeNode` class would have a `@ManyToOne` association with both `Tree` and `Node` entities, and you would add a new primary key attribute to the `TreeNode` class, which would be a composite of the primary keys of the `Tree` and `Node` entities.